# How to determine if address cannot be geocoded in JavaScript using MapQuest Map API

Tags: mapquest

I need to geocode bunch of addresses and pin point them on the map using MapQuest. I am using

```
geocodeAndAddLocations
```

method to do that. The only problem I have is I can't figure out if geocoding for a certain address failed or not. Does anyone know how to determine that?

Comment: do you have any sample code to post? would be much easier.

Comment: map.geocodeAndAddLocations(zipcodes);  I call this method with bunch of zipcodes and I want to know which zipcodes are not valid and failed to be geocoded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tested this code, but according to MapQuest API, it would be something like this:

```
map.geocodeAndAddLocations([
      {street:"555 17th St", postalCode:"80202"}
], function (response) {
    if (response.results.length == 0) { // FAILED!!!
        alert("can't geocode location");
    } else { // SUCCESS
        var location;
        for (j=0; j<response.results[i].locations.length; j++) {
            location = response.results[i].locations[j];
            alert('lat: ' + location.latLng.lat + ', lng: ' + location.latLng.lng);
        }
    }
});
```

but again, having more of your code would give a better idea what exactly you are doing and not doing.

Answer (score 0):

very simplest way...
use the following url in this jquery ajax to geocode. Even you are use mapquest 
This ajax returns the json object.

```
$.getJSON("http://nominatim.openstreetmap.org/reverse?format=json&lat="+lat+"&lon="+lon+"", function(data) {

             var  loc=data.display_name;    

                });
```

append your  lat and lng in the url.if unable to get the location details it throws the "unable to geocode " so you easily fix your problem.